# Nested blocks having arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block, anonymous-function, dsl

I have some serious troubles to understand blocks with arguments.
I would like to use such kind of Ruby code:

```
FooBar.foo do |foo_arg|
  bar do |bar_arg|
    define_method :hello!, foo_arg, bar_arg do
      "Hello, #{foo_arg} and #{bar_arg}!"
    end
  end
end

include FooBar
hello!(:Alice, :Bob) # => "Hello, Alice and Bob!"
```

And to do so, I added thoses lines:

```
module FooBar
  def self.foo &foo_block
    instance_eval &foo_block
  end

  def self.bar &bar_block
    instance_eval &bar_block
  end
end
```

But because arguments between pipes are specials, I've got a syntax error. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post your actual code? This does not appear to have any problems with it.

Comment: You're calling `instance_eval` but not passing in anything to the block, so what do you expect `foo_arg` to be? Also `define_method` should have one argument only. The others should be part of the supplied block: `define_method(:hello!) do |foo_arg, bar_arg|`.

Comment: Where do you get the `SyntaxError`? What is the *exact* wording of the `SyntaxError` you're getting? "Here is some code, it has some error in it, but I'm not gonna tell you what the error is" isn't exactly much to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module seems to work correctly. The issue is your usage of `define_method`. The parameters `foo_arg`, and `bar_arg` need to be part of the block passed to `define_method`.

```
module FooBar
  def self.foo(&foo_block)
    instance_eval &foo_block
  end

  def self.bar(&bar_block)
    instance_eval &bar_block
  end

  foo do |foo_arg|
    bar do |bar_arg|
      define_method :hello! do |foo_arg, bar_arg|
        "Hello, #{foo_arg} and #{bar_arg}!"
      end
    end
  end
end

include FooBar
hello!(:Alice, :Bob) # => "Hello, Alice and Bob!"
```

should do what you want.